# WireShark filtering just first part of the IP address

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I want to filter only addresses whose first half looks like this 239.145.x.x
How can I create a filter that will detect all IP addresses starting with 239.145?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of filters - ***capture*** filters, which use [pcap-filter](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) syntax, and if you're using a tool such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark.html), display/read filters, which use the [Wireshark display filter syntax](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html).

You don't specify which type of filter you're interested in, but if it's a capture filter you're looking for, then you'd use a filter such as:

```
net 239.145.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0
```

or:

```
net 239.145.0.0/16
```

If it's a Wireshark display/read filter you're looking for, then you'd use a filter such as:

```
ip.addr eq 239.145.0.0/16
```